# NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didReceiveData not working

Tags: iphone, delegates, nsurlconnection

I need some help regarding the NSURLConnectionDelegate method.

```
- (void)startDownload {
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:appRecord.imageURLString]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];   
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

imageConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];  
if(imageConnection) {
    activeDownload = [NSMutableData data];
}
}
```

I am using this method to initiate the NSURLConnection, but the

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

is not calling.. Need Help

Thanks in advance,
Shibin

Comment: Are you implementing lazy tables in your app?

Comment: Yes I am. can you help me in implementing this.? Pleasese

Comment: Why are you changing the code in icon down loader class? Don,t change that class.

Comment: If you want to increase the scrolling performance better try this http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Comment: hi warrior.. i am changing only the urlString for my image.. and in the "- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection" method i assign the image to the product object. can i contact you.. my id is smakmoideen@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

No single answer but:
1) Put some NSLogs in to display the URL and then validate that it is generated correctly and does return data

2) Check that you have properly declared that you conform to the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol in the .h

3) Are you threading or messing with the runloops ?  " Messages to the delegate will be sent on the thread that calls this method. By default, for the connection to work correctly the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run loop mode."

Comment: Thanks a Lot Andiih, but still its not working. i am getting the same output. I tried with NSlog and NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol is declared in .h file. I cant understand why its happening like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but do you do the `start` in your code ? I don't see it in your extract.
There should be a

```
 [imageConnection start]
```

somewhere in your code to trigger the start of the connection and get your delegate called asynchronously.